# htaccess redirects not only pages ending on .php but css.php files as well

Tags: css, .htaccess, gzip

First of all hello to the community and I hope to be able to contribute in the future.

Now straight to the point.
As my shared hosting does not have gzip compression enabled through .htaccess I had to compress my files using the first method posted on this page 
[Gzip compression for CSS files using PHP](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/3-ways-to-compress-css-files-using-php)

After doing so everything worked great until I used a htaccess command to redirect all pages ending on .php to the same without the extension like so 
website.com/index.php 
website.com/index

but this thing backfired in a way and now the css files that I gziped turning them into .php files are redirected to the original files without the

at the beginning and the 

at the end of the css documents.

Please advise what can I do to make it so that the css files are not redirected, but only the pages are.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing another rewrite rule for all *.css.php files that proceeds the one you are having the issue with. And be sure the make it the last rule [L] when a css match is found.

Comment: Well the rewrite rule that I use is the following

RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

What would be the one for the CSS as the one that I just mentioned is a rule that I found somewhere around the web and I did not write it myself.